# Whois list of Top Level Domain against their corresponding registrar

Tags: whois, tld

I'm trying to find a list of TLD's to their corresponding whois server, for example

.com americanWhoisServer
.net someOtherWhoisServer
.au australianWhoisServer

In the end i'm aiming for something like a Dictionary where the key is the TLD and the value is the whois server address (eg whois.apnic.net).

Ah snap, i just realised that i am given the IP addresses and not domain names but a list could still come in handy.

How can i determine which whois server to use given a IP address? Guess and check?

Answer (score 5):

You can get the official (?) tld list from http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt and then query the IANA whois server (whois.iana.org at port 43) for each tld to get information about it. Slightly more export-friendly and official than the HTML tld list at http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/.

Comment: this is non-exhaustive list. It doesn't contain such as co.uk. I found 2 collections of TLDs http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1
and 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ALaar6dLM7ZUc2MUtidVE4RXM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Romeno, agreed, IANA's list contains only topmost level domains. TLD's that have subdomains like co.uk tend to change from time to time, e.g. they add new "subdomains" like new.uk (not a real one). But I suppose Mozilla's one will be kept up-to-date (it's only 1 day old as of now).

Comment: Just for future reference of those concerned about what @Romeno brought up. .CO.UK is under .UK tld, and as such the whois information is the same for both .co.uk and .uk (Nominet)

Comment: @TomC that works for `.UK` because both `.UK` and `.CO.UK` are maintained by the same registry (Nominet) but this is not a generic rule. `.COM` and `.DE.COM` are not maintained by the same company, nor `.FR` and `.AVOCAT.FR` for just 2 examples

Answer (score 3):

Do not use a static, local list; whois servers may change in time (ok, not everyday, but it may happen); to find the server for a given domain or ip, start by querying the IANA whois server, basically, connect to whois.iana.org:43 and send the query string followed by "**\r\n**"; for example "**ibm.com\r\n**" or "**72.163.5.201\r\n**", the IANA whois server will then return an answer containing a "*hint*", for example, the query for 72.163.5.201 would return

```
% IANA WHOIS server 
% for more information on IANA, visit http://www.iana.org 
% This query returned 1 object

refer: whois.arin.net

inetnum: 72.0.0.0 - 72.255.255.255 organisation: ARIN status: ALLOCATED

whois: whois.arin.net

changed: 2004-08 source: IANA
```

now, parse the response searching for the "**whois:**" entry, extract the name of the whois server responsible for the IP or domain (whois.arin.net in this case) and repeat the query using that server; notice though, that in some cases (e.g. "com" domains and the verisign whois server) the second answer you'll get may return a referral to another whois server for example, here's the result of a query against the verisign whois for the verisign.com domain will return

```
Domain Name: VERISIGN-GRS.COM
Registrar: CSC CORPORATE DOMAINS, INC.
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 299
Whois Server: whois.corporatedomains.com
Referral URL: http://www.cscglobal.com/global/web/csc/digital-brand-services.html
Name Server: AV1.NSTLD.COM
Name Server: AV2.NSTLD.COM
Name Server: AV3.NSTLD.COM
Name Server: AV4.NSTLD.COM
Status: clientTransferProhibited https://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Status: serverDeleteProhibited https://www.icann.org/epp#serverDeleteProhibited
Status: serverTransferProhibited https://www.icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited
Status: serverUpdateProhibited https://www.icann.org/epp#serverUpdateProhibited
Updated Date: 12-jan-2016
Creation Date: 08-sep-2000
Expiration Date: 08-sep-2016
```

in such a case you'll need to locate the "**Whois Server:**" line, extract the whois server name (whois.corporatedomains.com in this case) and repeat the query; a last caveat, in some cases the "referral" may be returned even if the server is the one you just queried, so you should check such a condition to avoid an infinite loop

Comment: Here's an example of the process using C# (note: quick and dirty code, will need some cleanup but at least it works) http://pastebin.com/zWM8dHtU

Answer (score 0):

Each whois client has its own way of getting this information, since no standard was ever adopted.

GNU whois (as used on Debian) has a hardwired list (not a configuration file, a file included at compile-time, named tld_serv_list).

The whois client on FreeBSD uses an online (unofficial) list, maintained in the DNS, at whois-servers.net:

```
% dig +short CNAME fr.whois-servers.net 
whois.nic.fr.
% dig +short CNAME in.whois-servers.net 
whois.inregistry.net.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find the official IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority) list at http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/ a good starting/jumping off point. It lists the WHOIS (and nameservers) for all allocated TLDs and it's the official list, but not available in an "easy to export format"

Answer (score 0):

I regularly compile such a list from [IANA](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db) and [PSL](https://publicsuffix.org/) in XML: https://github.com/whois-server-list/whois-server-list

This list contains more than 900 top level domains and its respective whois servers. Additionally it includes more than 300 second level domains. The list gets updated frequently.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11227805)

Comment: Seriously? Do you want me to put the complete list here as an answer? That URI is the authoritative URI of that list. That's the place where the list will receive updates.

Answer (score 0):

a list of servers for TLD and SLD can be found at the web address https://whois.sld.ro/servers-list.html and at the only root domains https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

```
SLD / TLD Whois Server Last modified
.aaa whois.nic.aaa 2020-10-28
.gov.af whois.nic.af 2020-10-28
.com.af whois.nic.af 2020-10-28
.org.af whois.nic.af 2020-10-28
.edu.af whois.nic.af 2020-10-28
.ai whois.nic.ai 2020-10-28
.off.ai whois.nic.ai 2020-10-28
.com.ai whois.nic.ai 2020-10-28
....
```